# php mysql dump not working

Tags: php, mysql

I know there are several questions related to this issue. I tried many things but nothing worked so I posted this again.

I am trying to create a whole db backup in SQL format using php and mysqldump. I have the code working few days ago but then suddenly it stopped and it doesn't work any more.
Here is my code:

```
$q = "mysqldump --user=$mysqlUserName --password=$mysqlPassword --host=$mysqlHostName $mysqlDatabaseName > $mysqlExportPath";
exec($q, $output = array());
```

It gives me this warning and also does not create the sql backup.

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference
```

I am stuck, please help me. My server is on Codero and linux based.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you

```
$q = "/usr/bin/mysqldump -u $mysqlUserName -p $mysqlPassword -h $mysqlHostName $mysqlDatabaseName > $mysqlExportPath";
$output = array();
exec($q, $output);
```

Comment: as you are passing `$output` as second parameter with initializing it in `exec`  function results in warning.

Comment: I tried the same, The warning is gone but sql dump not created.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code `exec($q, $output = array());` **to** `exec($q, $output);`. It should work.

Please check [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function details on php.net. The 2nd argument takes a reference to an array. That's what the error messages is telling you. If you want to initialize the $output array, do it on a separate line before passing it to the function.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If still the sql dump is not created, please check the error log. It can be a permissions issue as well.

Comment: Ok. I am checking.

Comment: I have checked and found that it is set to "all privileges" for the user. There is no error in the error log file as well.

Comment: Ok, try another thing. Remove the variables and provide the values directly in the exec function for mysqldump command. Username, password, schema name and full path to the output file to save it to. All hard coded. Then see how it turns out. Let's say your db user name is root, password is abc123, schema name is db-project-xyz, your OS username is illusion and the file path is /home/illusion/db-dumps/db-project-xyz.sql, the mysqldump command should look like this.

Comment: ...continued from last comment... **mysqldump --user=root --password=abc123 --host=localhost db-project-xyz > /home/illusion/db-dumps/db-project-xyz.sql**. <br/> Replace the values with your real values and try passing it to the exec function. If it still doesn't work, try executing the same command you are passing to the exec function at the terminal command line just to be sure about what's happening.